# 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2' is a 'type' but is used like a variable?

Tags: xna-4.0

Right, I've looked it up on Google and I still can't figure out how to fix it. Any help?

```
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        Texture2D spritesheet;
        Rectangle sourceRect;
        Rectangle destinationRect;

        int spriteWidth = 50;
            int spriteHeight = 50;

            Texture2D maze;
            Vector2 mazePosition = Vector2(0f, 0f);

            Color[] spritetextureData;
            Color[] mazeTextureData;

            int direction = 0;
            bool persotHit = false;


        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how you create new objects:

```
Vector2 mazePosition = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
```

and not:

```
Vector2 mazePosition = Vector2(0f, 0f);
```

Note the word "new".

Comment: +1:  Good spot.  Also, you could use `Vector2 mazePosition = Vector2.Zero;`

Comment: @NeilKnight suggestion is slightly better than using the new operator as it doesn't add an additional object in the memory pool, which would then require collection. Vector2's are structs and don't require that you use the new operator to instantiate them.